# Webgl tiled layer rendering not working *Typescript

Tags: typescript, webgl, rendering

It is an assignment that requires sprite and map rendering. Both should work the same way but the map one isn't working. I've tried to let it draw some random staff on canvas but no matter how I change the attribute, nothing gets drawn.

Here's the code for rendering a single cell of the tile layer. I think the error most likely happens here.

```js
private renderTile(webGL: WebGLRenderingContext,
  viewport: Viewport,
  tileSet: TileSet, tile: number) {

  let canvasWidth: number = webGL.canvas.width;
  let canvasHeight: number = webGL.canvas.height;

  let texture: WebGLGameTexture = tileSet.getTexture();

  let spriteWidth: number = tileSet.getTileWidth(); //canvasWidth/tiledLayer.getMinimumVisibleColumn(0);
  let spriteHeight: number = tileSet.getTileHeight(); //canvasWidth/tiledLayer.getMinimumVisibleRow(0);

  let spriteLeft: number = tile % tileSet.getColumns();
  let spriteTop: number = Math.floor(tile / tileSet.getColumns());

  let spriteXInPixels: number = (spriteLeft * tileSet.getTileWidth() + tileSet.getTileSpacing() * (spriteLeft + 1));
  let spriteYInPixels: number = (spriteTop * tileSet.getTileHeight() + tileSet.getTileSpacing() * (spriteTop + 1));

  let spriteXTranslate: number = (spriteXInPixels - (canvasWidth / 2)) / (canvasWidth / 2);
  let spriteYTranslate: number = (spriteYInPixels - (canvasHeight / 2)) / (canvasHeight / 2);

  this.meshTranslate.setX(spriteXTranslate);
  this.meshTranslate.setY(-spriteYTranslate);

  let defaultWidth: number = canvasWidth;
  let defaultHeight: number = canvasHeight;
  let scaleX: number = 2 * spriteWidth / defaultWidth;
  let scaleY: number = 2 * spriteHeight / defaultHeight;
  this.meshScale.set(scaleX, scaleY, 0.0, 0.0); //1.0, 1.0);

  MathUtilities.identity(this.meshTransform);
  MathUtilities.model(this.meshTransform, this.meshTranslate, this.meshRotate, this.meshScale);

  let texCoordFactorX: number = spriteWidth / texture.width;
  let texCoordFactorY: number = spriteHeight / texture.height;

  let texCoordShiftX: number = (spriteLeft * tileSet.getTileWidth() + tileSet.getTileSpacing() * (spriteLeft + 1)) / texture.width; //spriteLeft/texture.width;
  let texCoordShiftY: number = (spriteTop * tileSet.getTileHeight() + tileSet.getTileSpacing() * (spriteTop + 1)) / texture.height; //spriteTop/texture.height;

  webGL.bindBuffer(webGL.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertexDataBuffer);
  webGL.bindTexture(webGL.TEXTURE_2D, texture.webGLTexture);

  let a_PositionLocation: GLuint = this.webGLAttributeLocations.get(this.A_POSITION);
  webGL.vertexAttribPointer(a_PositionLocation, this.FLOATS_PER_TEXTURE_COORDINATE, webGL.FLOAT, false, this.TOTAL_BYTES, this.VERTEX_POSITION_OFFSET);
  webGL.enableVertexAttribArray(a_PositionLocation);
  let a_TexCoordLocation: GLuint = this.webGLAttributeLocations.get(this.A_TEX_COORD);
  webGL.vertexAttribPointer(a_TexCoordLocation, this.FLOATS_PER_TEXTURE_COORDINATE, webGL.FLOAT, false, this.TOTAL_BYTES, this.TEXTURE_COORDINATE_OFFSET);
  webGL.enableVertexAttribArray(a_TexCoordLocation);

  let u_MeshTransformLocation: WebGLUniformLocation = this.webGLUniformLocations.get(this.U_MESH_TRANSFORM);
  webGL.uniformMatrix4fv(u_MeshTransformLocation, false, this.meshTransform.getData());
  let u_SamplerLocation: WebGLUniformLocation = this.webGLUniformLocations.get(this.U_SAMPLER);
  webGL.uniform1i(u_SamplerLocation, texture.webGLTextureId);
  let u_TexCoordFactorLocation: WebGLUniformLocation = this.webGLUniformLocations.get(this.U_TEX_COORD_FACTOR);
  webGL.uniform2f(u_TexCoordFactorLocation, texCoordFactorX, texCoordFactorY);
  let u_TexCoordShiftLocation: WebGLUniformLocation = this.webGLUniformLocations.get(this.U_TEX_COORD_SHIFT);
  webGL.uniform2f(u_TexCoordShiftLocation, texCoordShiftX, texCoordShiftY);

  webGL.drawArrays(webGL.TRIANGLE_STRIP, this.INDEX_OF_FIRST_VERTEX, this.NUM_VERTICES);
}
```

Comment: [There's nothing wrong with the code you posted](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/w3o42dgh/). The issue is somewhere in code you didn't post. That said, the code you posted takes no input for position of where to draw the tile. You ask for tile 20 it will ways draw it in the same place. Also viewport is never used.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I will go check other parts of the rendering system.